# How can i send me money from Spain to my russian bank account?

Tags: europe, money, spain, russia, exchange

I am Spaniard but now I am studying in Russia and due to sanctions I can no longer transfer money between my accounts. Does anyone know how I can send money from Spain to Russia?

Thank you.